# Android Materials draggable-profile

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I've been looking on how to implement the following new Material's style profile:

[image]

I want to be able to pull the separator between the image view and the bottom view up and down. I couldn't find any example or figure out how to do that.

This is the best I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
/>

<fully.qualified.name.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/header"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm new to Materials.